# How to render JSON response in Play framework v2.0 (latest build from GIT)

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to render some response like this

```
def doAjax = Action { request =>
    object MyResult {
        val resultCode = 0
        val resultTextMessage = "sss" 
    }
    Ok(Json(MyResult)) // It's not working anymore - not compiling in v2.0!
}
```

but how to map my object (MyResult) to JSON with Play 2.0? 
In Play 1.0 with scala module I did successfully the following:

```
def dosomeaj = {
    object MyResult{
        val resultCode = 0
        val resultTextMessage = "sss" 
    }
    Json(MyResult) // It's working in 1.0
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure this question makes sense since the “latest build from GIT” is likely to change over the time…

Comment: This question about RC1 from Git and it is more stable than Beta. Anyway in Beta there is no any JSon support.

Comment: @Julien Richard-Foy... everything is changing over the time ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### EDIT2

New [Wiki link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJsonRequests) for v2.1. The old link below is not working anymore.

### EDIT

We'll all be happy to read the new Wiki entry for this point. Check [this](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Scalajson) out

---

### PREVIOUS

Here is the comment from the community about the state of Json support in play 2.0.
[link to Post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/VeVacV4CU1o/Zm5gzwF7PScJ)

They are moving from Jackson to a philosophy inspired by [SJSON](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/07/sjson-now-offers-type-class-based-json.html) that offers more control on the un/marshalling, that brings facilities to manage them, w/o the overhead of Reflection (which I agree with them is a pain for performance and is fragile against Class changes...)

So here is what you can read on the post:

```
case class Blah(blah: String)

// if you want to directly serialize/deserialize, you need to write yourself a formatter right now
implicit object BlahFormat extends Format[Blah] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): Blah = Blah((json \ "blah").as[String])
    def writes(p: Blah): JsValue = JsObject(List("blah" -> JsString(p.blah)))

}

def act = Action { implicit request =>
   // to get a Blah object from request content
   val blah = Json.parse(request.body.asText.get).as[Blah]

   // to return Blah as application/json, you just have to convert your Blah to a JsValue and give it to Ok()
   Ok(toJson(blah))
}
```

In the second link ([SJSON](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/07/sjson-now-offers-type-class-based-json.html)), I propose you to pay special attention to the generic formatting possible by using `case class` and their deconstruction method (`unapply`).

Comment: I've published another solution as answer - look at this too.

Comment: I really don't know why Play2 now required explicit manual mapping to JsValue. It's maybe good sometimes but useless for simple response mapping like my sample :(

Comment: Yes, but really it just miss a very few pieces of code in the Template.scala source. Anyway, I'm gonna link this question with a question to the group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/VeVacV4CU1o

Comment: Thank you Andy! I agree Reflection is bad for performance of course and I understand why it's now required to write marshalling code. I think also there is another way to dynamically compile/generate marshalling code too within framework :) Anyway it's working now, Thank you!

Comment: @andypetrella, please see my comment below. I do not think play is moving from jackson/jerkson to SJSON, Pascal only mentioned that the parser was inspired by it and the parser should be the preferred way of handling JSON, however, there are situations where falling back on to Jerkson can be desirable and that should be always an option

Comment: I will work on the wiki entry today, that should clarify things

Comment: OK great, I'll update the answer with a pointer to your page then, keep me up to date. Thank you. Indeed, I probably extended too far the migration step. In my understanding, they will keep the abstraction, but with a SJSON phylosophy, that will leave you handle the way to un/marshal you model object. I'm gonna add "phylosophy" around SJON then.

Answer (score 6):

Play 2 comes with Jerkson

```
case class Blah(blah: String)
import com.codahale.jerksHon.Json._
def act = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(generate(parse[Blah](request.body.asText.get))).as("application/json")
}
```

This code will deserialize and reserialize the json.

For more information https://github.com/codahale/jerkson

Comment: Thank you Ivan! But if you look the answer above they are moving from Jerkson to SJSON. But your workaround is smaller than the "official" :)

Comment: @admob, I think you misunderstood that comment from Pascal. Play's parser is only *inspired* by SJSON (or liftJSON). Underneath it is using jerkson/jackson and I am not aware of any plans of changing that. So while the preferred way of handling JSON will be always through the provided parser and toJson(..) One always can fall back on to Jerkson if needed Ok(com.codahale.jerksHon.Json.generate(Map("1"->"2")).as("application/json")

Comment: Thank you, poko! Now I get it more precisely.

Answer (score 5):

I've found this solution in Play integration tests right now.

It's require to define in app/models/MyResult2.scala with this content:

```
case class MyResult2(resultCode: Int, resultTextMessage: String)

object Protocol {
    implicit object MyResult2Format extends Format[MyResult2] {
        def writes(o: MyResult2): JsValue = JsObject(
            List("resultCode" -> JsNumber(o.resultCode),
                "resultTextMessage" -> JsString(o.resultTextMessage)
            )
        )

        def reads(json: JsValue): MyResult2 = MyResult2(
            (json \ "resultCode").as[Int],
            (json \ "resultTextMessage").as[String]
        )
    }
}
```

And after this you can use it in your controller class like this:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import models._
import models.Protocol._

object Application extends Controller {    
    def doAjax = Action { request =>
        Ok(toJson(MyResult2(0, "Ney")))
    }
}
```

It's now required some manual static marshalling code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'play.api.mvc.as'

```
  def demo = Action {

    ....


    Ok(jsonString).as("text/json")

  }
```