# How to serve XML and JSON with Play! 2.0

Tags: xml, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm toying around with building a simple application to get my feet wet with Play! 2.0. I would like to be able to serve my resources as XML (ATOM feed, really) and JSON. I know how to do it in 1.2.x, but that way doesn't seem to work with 2.0. Does anyone know how to do it? Examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For JSON I would recommend you to look at this question [How to render JSON response in Play framework v2.0 (latest build from GIT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695335/how-to-render-json-response-in-play-framework-v2-0-latest-build-from-git/8695738#8695738)

XML is far more simpler since you can just call return the result with code like this:

```
Ok(Xml(xmlString))
```

But the cleaner way, fot using this functionality is probably to write your own template under `views/xml` like `mdo.scala.xml` could be

```
@(mdo:MyDomainObject)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyDomainObject>
  <name>@mdo.name</name>
  <desc>@mdo.desc</desc>
  <kws>
  @mdo.keywords map { k=>
    <kw>k</kw>
  }
  </kws>
</MyDomainObject>
```

Then in your Controller

```
def c = Action {
  val o = MyDomainObject("mine", "for example", List("stack", "over", "flow"))
  Ok(views.xml.mdo(o))
}
```

Otherwise, you maybe have the similar toXml function to toJson with the help of a marshaling library

Comment: I'll give you the checkmark, but here is a necessary thing you need to do in addition to what you have mentioned. To be valid, your first line must be something like `@(posts: Seq[Post])<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. If you don't do that, your first line won't be an xml declaration like it should. Bug? Probably.

Comment: NO this line is mandatory! I just forgot the mention it. Let me add it. Actually it is part of the XML spec, this line is always encoded in UTF-8 and is used by parsers in order to know which encoding is used in the document (and the XML version, but it isn't so much used actually...)

Comment: The problem still exists in your solution. The first line of your generated XML is actually empty. You need to put the declaration immediately after the parameters for play to render it right. That's a bug to me.

Comment: Ok you mean that Play! is adding a \n after its parameters list ... MMmh yes, kind of a bug, I'll check this out and discuss with them. Thanks